# laravel many to many

Tags: php, laravel

Ребята помогите!!!))) Подскажите как мне добавить к объекту выборки поле quantity

```
r_id|i_id|quantity  
1   |  3 |   250гр  
1   |  1 |     1уп  
1   |  2 |     500мл
```

Ну связь m-t-m работает, только в нее нужно добавить поле quantity в объект выборки..
Подскажите пожалуйста...очень надо!

Answer (score 1):

Если промежуточная таблица (называется Pivot) содержит не только колонки с ID-шниками, то необходимо их указать:

`return $this->belongsToMany('SomeModel')->withPivot('quantity');`

после этого к выборке, в таблице pivot, добавятся эти колонки и у Вас будет к ним доступ.